# opencv check if camera attached before calling cv::VideoCapture::open

Tags: c++, opencv, webcam

I am trying to open a webcam with opencv ,but the app is crashing when there is no camera attached.
I tried to wait for the camera to open with a simple timer but cv::VideoCapture::isOpened() is always returning true event when I have called open with no camera attached.My code looks like this:

```
void Widget::on_videoButton_clicked()
{
    //1.OPEN THE CAMERA
  capWebcam.open(0);
  startTimer->start(700);
}

void Widget::startTimerTimeout()
{

    if(capWebcam.isOpened()==false)
    {
        QMessageBox message;
        message.setText(" Camera not detected");
        message.exec();
        return;
    }

    //2.SHOW THE DIALOG

    mDialog.show();
   //3.START THE TIMER
    tmrTimer->start(100);
}
```

Here are my timers in the constructor for this to make sense:

```
tmrTimer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(tmrTimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(processFrameAndUpdateGui()));

    startTimer=new QTimer(this);
    startTimer->setSingleShot(true);
    connect(startTimer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(startTimerTimeout()));
```

Is there another way to check if there is a camera attached before starting the process of capturing frames?I apologize if this is obvious as I am new to openvc and the docs on opencv haven't been so helpful with the issue.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: try to use cv::VideoCapture(-1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,how do you mean I can use I check if a camera is attached? I tried to append that line to the end of my constructor and it causes the dialog to choose a video device(shows my integrated camera) .If I run the application on a machine with no attached camera nothing is shown and isOpen always returns true like before.

Comment: sorry I don't have opencv on my device, instead of give the ID of your cam using capWebcam.open(0);  you can try  capWebcam.open(-1) , assuming that capWebcam is your cam struct